# Wifi is Working but the F12(Wifi Key) is constantly glowing orange

Tags: wireless, 13.10, hp-pavilion

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy one month ago and have been using it regularly. The WiFi has worked fine until today, when I connected my laptop (HP Pavillion n-013tx) to an Ethernet cable and when I disconnected from it. I realized that the WiFi button light was orange although the WiFi seems to be working fine even now.

I have been trying to find the solution to this problem for hours now but can't find the problem with this description anywhere.

Output of `rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Moreover I have noticed that the speed of connection has also decreased pretty much.